# Where do I put Google Maps logic in Sencha-Touch 2? Multiple markers

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, google-maps-mobile

I have a functioning Google Map running on Google Appengine.

I want to turn this into a mobile friendly interface by using (maybe) [Sencha Touch 2](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/). Maybe I'm supposed to know [Sencha EXT JS4](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/) as well but I can't see it stated anywhere in their docs.

I don't know JavaScript very well. This is my 'learn by doing' app.

I've been reading the examples in documentation for Sencha Touch 2 but it stops short after getting some TabPanels with basic html and images.

There are some other examples on github for Sencha Touch 2 MVC & forms which I'd like to work on but the first step is to re-create my functional map.

I have included the current working Google Maps loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < pubs.length; ++i) {
    (function (address, name, phone, price, icon, lat, lng, boing) {
        var posi = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        if(boing == 'true') {
            var bounce = google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE;
        };
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            animation: bounce,
            map: beerMap.map,
            //changed this to beerMap
            icon: icon,
            shadow: shadow,
            position: posi,
            title: name
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            content_string = '<div id=content>' + '<div id="infoWindow">' + '</div>' + '<h2 id="pubName" class="pubName">' + name + '</h2>' + '<div id="pubAddress">' + '<p><b>' + address + '</b>' + '<div id="pubPhone" class="pubPhone">' + '<p>Phone: ' + phone + '<p>Halvliterpris: NOK <b>' + price + '</b>';
            bubble.setContent(content_string);
            bubble.open(beerMap.map, marker);
        });
    })(pubs[i], pub_name[i], pub_phone[i], beer_price[i], marker_icon[i], pub_lat[i], pub_lng[i], pub_bounce[i]);
}
```

./app/app.js

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});
Ext.application({
    name: 'app',
    appFolder: 'static/app',
    controllers: ['Home'],
    launch: function () {
        console.log('Ext.application ~ launch');
        Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            fullscreen: true,
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
            items: [{
                title: 'Home',
                iconCls: 'home'
            }, {
                title: 'Beer',
                iconCls: 'locate',
                xtype: 'map'
            }, {
                title: 'Gigs',
                iconCls: 'star'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

./app/controller/Home.js

```
Ext.define('app.controller.Home', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views: ['HomePage'],
    init: function() {

        console.log('Home controller init method...');
    }
});
```

./app/view/HomePage.js

```
Ext.define('app.view.HomePage', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.homepage',
    config: {
        html: '<img src="http://staging.sencha.com/img/sencha.png" />'
    },
    initialize: function () {
        console.log("InitComponent for homepage");
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Comment: I've had no success here or on the Sencha forums. Am I asking the wrong question?

Answer (score 1):

In my demo APP I have put my marker logic in the maprender method:

First the controller's `init` method:

```
/**
  * The init method will be executed first. Here we define how this controller should behave.
  */
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'viewport' : {
            activeitemchange : 'handleItemChange'
        },
        'map' : {
            maprender : 'onGMapRender'
        }
    });
},
```

Then my method `GMapRender()`:

```
/**
  * This method will be invoked after the google maps is rendered.
  * Here we will define the current user location.
  */
onGMapRender: function(comp, map) {

},
```

In the method GMapRender (actually it is the method **maprender** You have the map object where you can do fun stuff with the Google Maps object.

Hope this help you in the right direction.